# Confusing Switch/Case results

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Of course before posting this error I searched the heck out it. The code below returns: **error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'** in two spots. Am I misunderstanding why the code below isn't returning a string? Thinking to myself what advice Stack Overflow might give I've tried my best to explicitly cast to a string but have only managed to confuse myself.

```
public static class Bob
{
    public static string Response(string statement)
    {
        string teststring = statement;

        bool IsAllUpper(string input)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetter(input[i]) && !Char.IsUpper(input[i]))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        switch(teststring)
        {
        case IsAllUpper(teststring) && teststring.EndsWith("?"):
            string final1 = "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!";
            return final1;   

        case teststring.EndsWith("?"):
            string final2 = "Sure";
            return final2;

        default:
            string final3 = "Whatever.";
            return final3;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "This is the end";
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", Response(input));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `switch(teststring)` you're asking the code to switch on *string* values, e.g. "foo" and "bar". However, your `case`s are *boolean* values: `IsAllUpper(teststring)` and `teststring.EndsWith("?")` both return booleans.

Consider replacing the switch block with if statements, something like

```
if (IsAllUpper(teststring) && teststring.EndsWith("?")) {
    string final1 = "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!";
    return final1;
}   

if (teststring.EndsWith("?")) {
    string final2 = "Sure";
    return final2;
}

string final3 = "Whatever.";
return final3;
```

or, for maximum <s>conciseness</s> obscurity, the one-liner:

```
return teststring.EndsWith("?") ? (IsAllUpper(teststring) ? "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!" : "Sure") : "Whatever."
```

Comment: I had considered an if-else tree but backed away as I worked through the problem and saw the complexity increase as I added more cases but I guess that's the consensus. Much appreciated. I'll rework my code.